# Implementing LinearRegression model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am willing to implement a tensor flow model for LinearRegression with hidden layers.

I have referred these tutorials for making linear regression using tensorflow,

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.py

https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/?completed=/tensorflow-deep-neural-network-machine-learning-tutorial/

Here is the code of mine:

```
class LinearRegression:

    def __init__(self, x, y, data_type, learning_rate=0.01, epochs=100):
        """
        Constructor to initialize the instance variables

        :param x: independent variable X

        :param y: dependent variable y

        :param data_type: The data-type of dependent and independent variable

        :param learning_rate: The learning rate of the neural network. Default: 0.01

        :param epochs: Number of epochs. Default 100
        """

        data_types = {
            "int8": tf.int8,
            "int16": tf.int16,
            "int32": tf.int32,
            "int64": tf.int64,
            "float16": tf.float16,
            "float32": tf.float32,
            "float64": tf.float64
        }

        # Assign independent and dependent variables
        self.__independent_variable = x
        self.__dependent_variable = y

        # Assign data-types, learning rate and epochs
        self.data_type = data_types[data_type]
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs

        # Get the shape of input
        # self.input_shape = None
        # try:
        #     self.input_shape = self.__independent_variable.shape[1]
        # except KeyError:
        #     self.input_shape = 1

        # hidden layers
        self.__hidden_layers = []

        # placeholders
        self.X = tf.placeholder(self.data_type)
        self.y = tf.placeholder(self.data_type)

        # cost function
        self.cost_function = None

        # optimizer
        self.optimizer = None

    def add_hidden_layer(self, weight_shape, activation_function="relu", nodes=100, bias=None):
        """
        This method will add the hidden layer to our neural net. Note last hidden layer you are adding will be an
        output layer.

        :param weight_shape: The shape of the weight

        :param activation_function: The activation function to be used. Supported: relu(Default), sigmoid, tanh

        :param nodes: No of nodes for the bias, default is 100

        :param bias: Default is 0's of no of nodes.

        :return: True if the layer is added else will return False
        """
        if bias is None:
            bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(weight_shape[1]))
        weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(weight_shape, minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0))
        layer = None

        # Count of hidden layer
        hidden_layer_count = len(self.__hidden_layers)

        # For the formula Y = mx+b
        if activation_function == "relu":
            if hidden_layer_count==0:
                layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.X, weight)+bias)
            else:
                layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][0], weight)+bias)
        elif activation_function == "sigmoid":
            if hidden_layer_count == 0:
                layer = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.X, weight) + bias)
            else:
                layer = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][0], weight) + bias)
        elif activation_function == "tanh":
            if hidden_layer_count == 0:
                layer = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(self.X, weight) + bias)
            else:
                layer = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][0], weight) + bias)
        self.__hidden_layers.append([layer, weight, bias])
        print("Added layer")

    def train(self, optimizer="adam"):
        """
        This method will train the model. Only two famous optimizers are supported

        1. adam (Default)
        2. gradient_descent

        :param optimizer: Optizers will reduce the cost function. Supported: adam(Default), gradient_descent

        :return: None
        """
        hidden_layer_count = len(self.__hidden_layers)
        self.cost_function = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][0]-self.y, 2)
                                           / (2*self.__dependent_variable.shape[0]))
        if optimizer == "adam":
            self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost_function)
        else:
            self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost_function)

        W = tf.Variable(0.40, name="weight")
        b = tf.Variable(0.40, name="bias")
        # Initialize the global variables
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run(init)
            for epoch in range(self.epochs):
                session.run(self.optimizer, feed_dict={self.X: self.__independent_variable, self.y: self.__dependent_variable})
                c = session.run(self.cost_function, feed_dict={self.X: self.__independent_variable, self.y: self.__dependent_variable})
                weight = session.run(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][1])
                bias = session.run(self.__hidden_layers[hidden_layer_count-1][2])
                if epoch%100==0:
                    print("Weight: ", weight, "Cost: ", c, "Bias: ", bias)
            return weight, bias
```

And I have tested with some sample input:

```
import numpy

# Dataset
train_X = numpy.asarray([[ 3.3  ],
       [ 4.4  ],
       [ 5.5  ],
       [ 6.71 ],
       [ 6.93 ],
       [ 4.168],
       [ 9.779],
       [ 6.182],
       [ 7.59 ],
       [ 2.167],
       [ 7.042],
       [10.791],
       [ 5.313],
       [ 7.997],
       [ 5.654],
       [ 9.27 ],
       [ 3.1  ]])
train_Y = numpy.asarray([[1.7  ],
       [2.76 ],
       [2.09 ],
       [3.19 ],
       [1.694],
       [1.573],
       [3.366],
       [2.596],
       [2.53 ],
       [1.221],
       [2.827],
       [3.465],
       [1.65 ],
       [2.904],
       [2.42 ],
       [2.94 ],
       [1.3  ]])

l = LinearRegression(train_X, train_Y, "float32", epochs=1000)
l.add_hidden_layer([1, 17])
#l.add_hidden_layer([10, 10])
l.add_hidden_layer([17, 1])
weight, bias = l.train(optimizer="adam")
```

I get output like this:

```
Weight:  [[ 0.7321346 ]
 [ 0.30761123]
 [-0.49645996]
 [ 0.8884759 ]
 [ 0.43539715]
 [ 0.6100311 ]
 [-0.21072604]
 [ 0.8822198 ]
 [-0.8709421 ]
 [ 0.1667776 ]
 [ 0.8926308 ]
 [-0.90756726]
 [-0.41226315]
 [ 0.21427989]
 [ 0.17000389]
 [-0.9373965 ]
 [ 0.16003537]] Cost:  7.7810783 Bias:  [-0.01]
Weight:  [[ 0.7321346 ]
 [ 0.30761123]
 [-0.5783508 ]
 [ 0.8262489 ]
 [ 0.43539715]
 [ 0.6100311 ]
 [-0.28867453]
 [ 0.77843475]
 [-0.8709421 ]
 [ 0.05801708]
 [ 0.78117526]
 [-0.90756726]
 [-0.41226315]
 [ 0.21427989]
 [ 0.17000389]
 [-0.983428  ]
 [ 0.16003537]] Cost:  0.119424164 Bias:  [-0.00681436]
Weight:  [[ 0.7321346 ]
 [ 0.30761123]
 [-0.5923004 ]
 [ 0.82624584]
 [ 0.43539715]
 [ 0.6100311 ]
 [-0.30400994]
 [ 0.76900154]
 [-0.8709421 ]
 [ 0.04737379]
 [ 0.7730713 ]
 [-0.90756726]
 [-0.41226315]
 [ 0.21427989]
 [ 0.17000389]
 [-1.0034373 ]
 [ 0.16003537]] Cost:  0.08574117 Bias:  [0.09325708]
```

I can clearly see that the cost function is decreasing but I am not that much experienced in tensorflow so I don't know whether my implementation is correct or not(I tried my level best!) and also don't know how to predict for future arrays. Could you help me or provide ant guidance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can just wait until convergence and check the weights versus the true weights that you can get from other publicly available implementations of LR (i.e. sklearn).